# Rate of change of angle vs rate of change of distance of a point on a circle from a fixed point

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

English isn't my first language and my mathematics is very rusty at this point, so the title might need to be edited.

Perhaps this is trivial, but my mathematics isn't very good and Google searching proves futile. And by the way, this is ***NOT HOMEWORK***, I haven't been in schools for years now.

Let there be a circle with radius $r$, call its center $C$, the coordinate of $C$ is not important in the question.

Let there be a point $A$, its coordinate is irrelevant, but there are two important details: 1, the point is strictly outside of the circle, and 2, the coordinate of the point is fixed.

Now let there be a point $B$ on the circle, the point $B$ has variable coordinate but it is always on the circle, I want to find the rate of change of the angle $\angle{ACB}$ (in radians) over the rate of change of the segment $AB$.

In other words, represent the position of $B$ with the $\angle{ACB}$ and denote it with $\theta$, what is $\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial AB}$ for any given $\theta$ at its immediate vicinity?

I tried to solve it but my calculus isn't very good, I only worked out the relationship between $\theta$ and $AB$.

[image]

Let the segment $AC$ intersect with the circle at point $D$, from the definition of the circle, $CD = r$. From point $B$ draw a line perpendicular to $AC$, the line intersects $AC$ at $E$, call $\angle{EBD} \ \alpha$. We have two right triangles here, and $AB = \sqrt{EB ^ 2 + (ED + AD) ^ 2}$, denote length $AD$ with $d$, $d$ is constant.

Now we bisect $\angle{\theta}$, there is an isosceles triangle, and we have another right triangle, two same angles, the triangles are congruent...

So $\alpha = \frac{\theta}{2}$.

With some trigonometry I have this complicated expression, let $l = AB$:

$l = \sqrt{(2r \cdot sin(\frac{\theta}{2}) \cdot sin(\frac{\theta}{2}) + d) ^ 2 + (2r \cdot sin(\frac{\theta}{2}) \cdot cos(\frac{\theta}{2})) ^ 2}$

$sin ^ 2 (\frac{\theta}{2}) = \frac{1 - cos (\theta)}{2}$ and $sin(\frac{\theta}{2}) \cdot cos(\frac{\theta}{2}) = \frac{sin(\theta)}{2}$

Now the expression becomes:

$l = \sqrt{r^2 + r ^ 2 \cdot cos ^ 2 (\theta) + r ^ 2 \cdot sin ^ 2 (\theta) + d^2 + 2rd - 2r^2 \cdot cos(\theta) - 2rd \cdot cos(\theta)}$

Because $sin^2(\theta) + cos^2(\theta) = 1$:

$l = \sqrt{2r^2 + d^2 + 2rd - 2r^2 \cdot cos(\theta) - 2rd \cdot cos(\theta)}$

I don't know if I have reduced the expression to the simplest terms, I am not a mathematician, and this is as far as I can go with only mathematics.

I am not a programmer, either (that is to say I am not professional/employed for my programming skills), but I have very good programming skills, and I wrote the following program to do numerical analysis:

```
from math import cos, pi


class Model:
    def __init__(self, r, d):
        self.constant = 2 * r * r + d * d + 2 * r * d
        self.modifier = 2 * r * (r + d)

    def a_to_d(self, a):
        return (self.constant - self.modifier * cos(a)) ** 0.5

    def multisect_analyze(self, parts):
        unit = pi / parts
        return [
            (
                length := self.a_to_d(p * unit),
                unit / (length - self.a_to_d((p - 1) * unit)),
            )
            for p in range(1, parts + 1)
        ]
```

For those of you not familiar with programming, basically the above code splits the semicircle into $n$ equal parts, and calculates the  the angle of the arc over difference between $l$ of the latest end of the current arc and that of the previous end of the current arc.

And the only thing I have found, is that the rate of change isn't constant:

```
In [2]: m = Model(5, 10)

In [3]: m.multisect_analyze(32)
Out[3]:
[(10.036049571378694, 2.7233269819874883),
 (10.143086706694143, 0.9172028953815868),
 (10.317894632150916, 0.5616150993620624),
 (10.555475835949178, 0.41322616795916367),
 (10.849507378113843, 0.3338919685347925),
 (11.192835125856996, 0.2859505853227061),
 (11.577928657389, 0.2549374694353237),
 (11.997248968910242, 0.23412834467406374),
 (12.44351266224506, 0.2199927349927239),
 (12.909859218715734, 0.21051891359007982),
 (13.389939860809694, 0.20449641542819524),
 (13.87794960162475, 0.20117379268027158),
 (14.368622008106088, 0.2000821100348848),
 (14.857202014429928, 0.2009389847189305),
 (15.339407711856605, 0.20359521040211118),
 (15.811388300841896, 0.20800594921868829),
 (16.269682573714647, 0.21421775535026186),
 (16.711180338396783, 0.22236753677646273),
 (17.133087917482047, 0.23269259736346354),
 (17.53289807347215, 0.24555346819932025),
 (17.908364261537113, 0.26147433123244407),
 (18.257478877242068, 0.28121071421326765),
 (18.578455065600767, 0.30586309509965326),
 (18.86971163473311, 0.33707315415114825),
 (19.129860637349413, 0.3773789998706264),
 (19.357697224757437, 0.43089993377079233),
 (19.552191428386056, 0.5047696465656277),
 (19.712481575811125, 0.6124816278590967),
 (19.837869098263333, 0.7829708132410149),
 (19.92781453297086, 1.0914925337112784),
 (19.98193456602312, 1.8140190404148353),
 (20.0, 5.43439867264346)]
```

Comment: The letters in the figure don't match those in the text.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I know they are different, but I assume people can all understand what's what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain your final formula at once from the cosine law:
$$
l^2=r^2+(r+d)^2-2r(r+d)\cos\theta.
$$
Differentiating gives:
$$
2l=2r(r+d)\sin\theta{d\theta\over dl}.
$$
You can invert this to find ${d\theta\over dl}$:
$$
{d\theta\over dl}={l\over r(r+d)\sin\theta}.
$$